# What to do when Process won't End

Tags: windows-7, command-line, process, visual-studio-2010, c++

I'm an amateur programmer and often run into this problem. I use visual studio and sometimes if I don't clear my input buffer input gets thrown into the next awaiting `cin` and throws my program into an endless loop.

The problem is - I can't close the command prompt. I can't run my program again until the command prompt is close (I can't open another command prompt). I've tried to ctrl+alt+del and end the process there - it does nothing. I'm unsure what else to do except restart my computer... When I do this it closes automatically (and quickly), but then I can't cancel my restart I just kind of have to go through it.

What else can I do to end a process that will not end?

**Edit** Not sure why this was migrated here, i feel this is a windows problem looking for a windows solution. I thought superusers was for that.

Comment: Have you tried stopping or restarting it from visual studio? (the "stop" square button or from the menus)

Comment: You mean like Stop Debugging? It's stopped and it allows me to try to debug it, but when it's compiling I get an error that it cannot open my `.exe` file for writing which I only get when this problem happens (problem being cmd prompt won't close).

Comment: how about 'Debug -> Restart', or 'Debug -> Terminate All' from the menus?

Comment: I don't have either of these options under my Debug menu but i'll keep looking through my settings. I am running 2010 Express though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unticking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" under project settings.

I had the same issue when working with serial port. I close my app and it won't overwrite .exe when I try to start debugging again. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Install this program called [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), it can terminate any process, I have used it for years, and haven't met any process that this program can not terminate. It has a regular "terminate" function that usually works, and if that doesn't work, it has this "terminator" function that let's you try more than 10 methods of terminating a stubborn process.